# Why the asp code fail?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

```
HeaderStr = HeaderStr & "<link href="""&HB_ManageFolder&"/Include/ASBox/ASBox.css"" rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"">"&vbcrlf
```

But if I change `&HB_ManageFolder&` to  `& HB_ManageFolder &` it will work.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

&H starts a hexadecimal number

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know VBScript (which you are probably using with ASP) but as far as I know, it's quite similar to VBA.
And I know this issue from VBA: if you build strings with "&" and you don't leave blanks in between, VBA won't compile until you put the blanks in.

Probably it's the same issue here.
So, you just always have to use " & " instead of "&" and it will work.